# Guessing Same Number

Tags: c++

In a book about game programming, I have the following exercise.

> The user thinks of a number, and then the program tries to guess it, with the user providing feedback.

My method to solve this is just allowing the CPU to pick a random number between a high and a low (based off previous guesses) instead of the fast way to find out the number (guess the number halfway between the high and low). So it works, but there is an error in that the CPU guesses the same number more than once. Where did I go wrong and how do I fix it?

```
    enum statuses {NEUTRAL, HIGH, LOW};
            int status = NEUTRAL;
            int cpuguess, high = 100, low = 1;
            char winner, highorlow, playAgain;

            do {

                cout << "Guess My Number" << endl << endl;

                cout << "Press Enter to Play !" << endl;
                cin.ignore();
                cin.get();

                do {
                    cpuguess = getGuess(status, high, low);

                    cout << "Is your guess " << cpuguess << " ?" << endl;
                    cout << "(y/n)";
                    cin >> winner;
                    winner = toupper(winner);

                    if(winner == 'N')
                    {
                    WrongInputHL:
                        cout << "Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O" << endl;
                        cout << "(h/l)";
                        cin >> highorlow;
                        highorlow = toupper(highorlow);
                        if(highorlow == 'H')
                        {
                            status = HIGH;
                            high = cpuguess;
                        }
                        else if(highorlow == 'L')
                        {
                            status = LOW;
                            low = cpuguess;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            goto WrongInputHL;
                        }
                    }
                } while (winner == 'N');

                cout << "I won ! :D" << endl << endl;

                cout << "Do you want to play again ?" << endl;
                cout << "(y/n)" << endl;
                cin >> playAgain;
                playAgain = toupper(playAgain);
            }while(playAgain == 'Y');
```

All other advice to improve is also welcomed.

Comment: You need to include the function `getGuess` so that we don't have to Guess.

Comment: Re 'Any other advice in ways to improve , are welcomed too lol.': I'd advise you to stray away from using goto until you've gained more expertise (they're generally frowned upon and many would argue that you should never use them at all) - they are often (though not always, imo) an indicator that you have not properly structured your program and that your logic could be outlined in a better, clearer way.

Comment: omg gotos.... burn it

Comment: The construct you are looking for, the "recommended" one is to throw an exception rather than using a goto.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I've written a (somewhat sloppy) answer for the question which outlines how I think the program should be restructured. In my answer, I extracted taking input into a function which solves the problem at hand and improves readability.  I handled the user giving invalid input by asking for a new input (as did the topic creator) though I could see valid points for throwing exceptions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in this section

```
                {
                WrongInputHL:
                    cout << "Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O" << endl;
                    cout << "(h/l)";
                    cin >> highorlow;
                    highorlow = toupper(highorlow);
                    if(highorlow == 'H')
                    {
                        status = HIGH;
                        high = cpuguess;
                    }
                    else if(highorlow == 'L')
                    {
                        status = LOW;
                        low = cpuguess;
                    }
```

It seems like the basis of your algorithm is a binary search, however, notice how you set the high and low ends there. The high end could get repeated since it's potentially selectable.

Try this:

```
                WrongInputHL:
                    cout << "Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O" << endl;
                    cout << "(h/l)";
                    cin >> highorlow;
                    highorlow = toupper(highorlow);
                    if(highorlow == 'H')
                    {
                        status = HIGH;
                        high = cpuguess-1;
                    }
                    else if(highorlow == 'L')
                    {
                        status = LOW;
                        low = cpuguess+1;
                    }
```

This way if the number is too high, the new range becomes (low, cpuguess-1)
While if it's too low it becomes (cpuguess+1, high)
This will ignore the number the computer selected before.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I figure the others will help you with the logic of your program, so I'll help you with your structure; that is, how you've logically outlined the program and how I think you could do better.  Note that I've not actually run any of the code here - I don't have the environment to do so at the moment.

I started off by auto-formatting your code and migrating it away from do-while loops to simple while-loops. Additionally, I moved your variable declarations closer to where they are used.  In the real world, some coding standards forbid that last step, but I feel it improves readability of your program and that it would help you understand my logic.

```
enum statuses { NEUTRAL, HIGH, LOW };
int status = NEUTRAL;
char input;
int cpuguess, high = 100, low = 1;
bool playing = true; // use booleans to represent true/false state, rather than characters
while (playing) { // "playing" closer to declaration = arguably easier to read & find purpose
   cout << "Guess My Number" << endl << endl;
   cout << "Press Enter to Play !" << endl;
   cin.ignore();
   cin.get();

   bool gameWon = false;
   while (!gameWon) {
      cpuguess = getGuess(status, high, low);

      cout << "Is your guess " << cpuguess << " ?" << endl;
      cout << "(y/n)";
      cin >> input;
      gameWon = toupper(input) == 'Y';

      if (!gameWon)
      {
         status = NEUTRAL;
         while (status == NEUTRAL) {
            cout << "Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O" << endl;
            cout << "(h/l)";
            cin >> input;
            input = toupper(input);
            if (input == 'H') {
               status = HIGH;
               high = cpuguess;
            } else if (input == 'L') {
               status = LOW;
               low = cpuguess;
            }
         }
      }
   } 

   cout << "I won ! :D" << endl << endl;
   cout << "Do you want to play again ?" << endl;
   cout << "(y/n)" << endl;
   cin >> input;
   playing = toupper(input) == 'Y';
}
```

--

In your program, you often want the user to give one of two answers. In fact, we see code similar to

```
cout << "Is your guess " << cpuguess << " ?" << endl;
cout << "(y/n)";
cin >> input;
gameWon = toupper(input) == 'Y';
```

Three times! Perhaps, we could introduce a new function, say, getAnswer, which takes a question and two possible answers (ie: 'y' and 'n') and returns the user's answer?  Additionally, I've chosen to be consistent on printing uppercase Y/N options and have deemed '\0' as a value the user would never input. As a result, the program will no longer properly operate if option1 or option2 are lowercase.  There are many ways to handle this, such as verifying that option1 and option2 isupper(c) at the start of your getAnswer function, though I have not done so here.

```
char getAnswer(const char * question, const char option1, const char option2);

void main() { // or whatever entry-point signature you've used
   enum statuses { NEUTRAL, HIGH, LOW };
   int status = NEUTRAL;
   char input;
   int cpuguess, high = 100, low = 1;
   bool playing = true; // use booleans to represent true/false state, rather than characters
   while (playing) { // "playing" closer to declaration = arguably easier to read & find purpose
      cout << "Guess My Number" << endl << endl;
      cout << "Press Enter to Play !" << endl;
      cin.ignore();
      cin.get();

      bool gameWon = false;
      while (!gameWon) {
         cpuguess = getGuess(status, high, low);

         stringstream ss;
         ss << "Is your guess " << cpuguess << " ?";
         gameWon = getAnswer(ss.c_str(), 'Y', 'N') == 'Y';

         if (!gameWon) {
            status = getAnswer("Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O", 'H', 'L') == 'H' ? HIGH : LOW;
            if (status == HIGH)
               high = cpuguess;
            else
               low = cpuguess;
         }
      } 

      cout << "I won ! :D" << endl << endl;
      playing = getAnswer("Do you want to play again?", 'Y', 'N') == 'Y';
   }
}

char getAnswer(const char * question, const char option1, const char option2) {
   char response = '\0';
   while (response != option1 && response != option2) {
      cout << question << endl;
      cout << "(" << option1 << "/" << option2 << ")" << endl;
      cin >> response;
      response = toupper(response);
   }
   return response;
}
```

Awesome, our code looks a lot cleaner from just that, but we still haven't broken our code into logical pieces, so let's try doing that.  Note that I've moved some of your console output to outside of your outer while loop and changed 'is your guess' to 'is your number'.  Before, if a user stated they wanted to play again, they'd have to press enter after that which was annoying!

```
enum class GuessStatus { NEUTRAL, HIGH, LOW }; // I elected to use c++11's 'enum class' 

// these are called forward declarations
void runIntroduction();
void playGame();

// I elected to use const char * and const char here. They weren't necessary, though.
char getAnswer(const char * question, const char option1, const char option2);

void main() { // or whatever entry-point signature you've used
   runIntroduction();

   bool playing = true; // use booleans to represent true/false state, rather than characters
   while (playing) { // "playing" closer to declaration = arguably easier to read & find purpose
      playGame();
      playing = getAnswer("Do you want to play again?", 'Y', 'N') == 'Y';
   }
}

void runIntroduction() {
   cout << "Guess My Number" << endl << endl;
   cout << "Press Enter to Play !" << endl;
   cin.ignore();
   cin.get();
}

void playGame () {
   int guessHigh = 100, guessLow = 1;
   GuessStatus status = GuessStatus::NEUTRAL; // I'd suggest having GuessState::INITIAL = NEUTRAL to improve readability.  Either that, or throwing in a comment to describe why you use NEUTRAL.
   bool gameWon = false;
   while (!gameWon) {
      int cpuguess = getGuess(status, high, low);

      stringstream ss;
      ss << "Is your number " << cpuguess << " ?";
      gameWon = getAnswer(ss.c_str(), 'Y', 'N') == 'Y';

      if (!gameWon) {
         status = getAnswer("Too HIGH or Too LOW ? O_O", 'H', 'L') == 'H' ? GameStatus::HIGH : GameStatus::LOW;
         if (status == GameStatus::HIGH)
            high = cpuguess;
         else // status == GameStatus::LOW
            low = cpuguess;
      } 
   }
   cout << "I won ! :D" << endl << endl;
}

char getAnswer(const char * question, const char option1, const char option2) {
   char response = '\0';
   while (response != option1 && response != option2) {
      cout << question << endl;
      cout << "(" << option1 << "/" << option2 << ")" << endl;
      cin >> response;
      response = toupper(response);
   }
   return response;
}
```

That's all, feel free to ask questions if anything's confusing.

Comment: Finally, I should note that it's often considered bad practice to use `using namespace std;` as it pollutes the global namespace (as in, it increases chances of having conflicting method signatures).  Many developers instead type "std::cout", "std::endl", and "std::cin".

Comment: I used to type out std::cout but after taking my first class in C++ , he told me not to use it . But I believe reading it somewhere that its better practice to do so.

thank you for your answer tho , it really did clean somethings up. I got lost though at the part of
playing = getAnswer("Do you want to play again?", 'Y', 'N') == 'Y';
where playing is a bool value , if the function only returns a char how would it know to end the loop ? 
Im sorry I dont know how to do the text editing yet on this site. lol

Comment: Check the `==` part. The function gets an answer and sets "playing" to whether or not the response equals `'Y'`.  If the answer is `'Y'`, playing is thus set to true (`'Y' == 'Y'`). Otherwise, playing is set to false (`'Y' != 'N'`).  Once you reach the bottom of a while loop your program checks the condition in `while(condition)` to determine if it will run another iteration of its body.